# Dinamically resize size of widget inside a widget?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Basicly what I'm trying to do is to create a `QListWidget` that contains several `QTableWidget`s, and what I'm trying to achieve is that each time when row is inserted inside `QTableWidget`, QListWidgetItem needs to resize so the inserted row is visible. Is there easy way to do so?

This is what I came up with so far:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        main_window.resize(600, 400)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QWidget(main_window)

        self.list_widget = QtGui.QListWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.list_widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 580, 380))
        self.list_widget.setSpacing(5)

        self.list_widget.addItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem())
        self.list_widget.addItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem())

        self.table_widget_1 = QtGui.QTableWidget(0, 2, self.list_widget)
        self.table_widget_1.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Column 1', 'Column 2'])
        self.table_widget_1.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(1)
        self.table_widget_1.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)

        self.table_widget_2 = QtGui.QTableWidget(0, 2, self.list_widget)
        self.table_widget_2.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Column 1', 'Column 2'])
        self.table_widget_2.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(1)
        self.table_widget_2.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)

        self.list_widget.setItemWidget(
            self.list_widget.item(0),
            self.table_widget_1
        )

        self.list_widget.setItemWidget(
            self.list_widget.item(1),
            self.table_widget_2
        )

        self.table_widget_1.insertRow(self.table_widget_1.rowCount())
        self.table_widget_2.insertRow(self.table_widget_2.rowCount())
        main_window.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Test(main_window)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is how it looks so far...

[image]

Comment: please, provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have updated the code and the picture. As it can be seen, rows inserted inside `table_widget_1` and `table_widget_2` are not visible due to size restriction of `QListWidgetItem`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when size of `QTableWidget` changes (by adding new `QTableWidgetItem`) I need to figure out what's the actual size of whole `QTableWidget` and then update size of `QListWidgetItem` associated with that particular `QTableWidget`.

Comment: Why do you want to use QListWidget?

Comment: I mean it doesn't have to be `QListWidget` (it seemed appropriate to me to use some kind of a list). I want to make sure that users can add multiple `QTableWidget`s and that they can edit their items (added `QTableWidgetItem` have to be visible).

Comment: Initial idea why I wanted to use `QListWidget` is because of signals, e.g. if user double clicks `QListWidgetItem`, it gets deleted.

Comment: but having a QTableWidget on the item would no longer make it possible to use that signal.

Comment: Why is it necessary for the QTableWidget to show all the items ?, QTableWidget have a scrollbar that allows to do it, for example by rewriting its code I get the following: https://imgur.com/a/ihb9qRK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177550/discussion-between-sir-drinkscoffeealot-and-eyllanesc).